# Primary key column value as two column values combined with different format

Tags: mysql, sql, addition, multiple-columns

So I want to make a primary key that combines the year of a date value followed by - and then a foreign key value that is an order number.

Basically: 2010-244

This is what I tried, (I know I should parse a part of the date string):

> ORDERNR int(11) NOT NULL,
>     RECEIPTDATE DATE,
>   RECEIPTNR as RECEIPTDATE + "-" + ORDERNR INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
>   FOREIGN KEY (ORDERNR) REFERENCES ORDER(ORDERNR),
>     PRIMARY KEY (RECEIPTNR))
>   ENGINE=INNODB;

Comment: A primary key can be composed of multiple columns

Comment: Ok lets say I make a composite key:

PRIMARY KEY (RECEIPTDATE, ORDERNR) as RECEIPTNR)

First I want it to be displayed as RECEIPTNR this code does not work, and second how would I add the "-" between the keys?

Comment: SELECT CONCAT_WS('-',col1,col2) FROM my_table;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not offer function-based indexes (with the minor exception of indexing the leading characters in a string).  In other words, you want to create an index on an expression and MySQL does not support that.

If the "year" component of a date is unique, then the data can only have one date per year.  So, you can have a unique index on the entire date.

This would be accepted as a primary key:

```
unique (RECEIPTDATE, ORDERNR);
```

But this doesn't give you the uniqueness within a year.

Another alternative -- which I don't recommend, but I suggest because it might work -- is to store the date in a string in YYYY-MM-DD format.  Then you can do:

```
unique (RECEIPTDATESTRING(4), ORDERNR)
```

The alternative is to have a trigger that tests for uniqueness.

Further advice.  Don't make a composite primary key, particularly when one of the keys is only part of a column.  Instead, use a `unique` constraint on the fields and have an auto-incremented primary key.